# Add to home screen just once

Tags: google-chrome, web, web-applications, manifest, progressive-web-apps

I've implement **Add to home screen** (A2HS) prompt according to this article https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/.

The prompt is working fine but it has one disadvantage. When a user tries to open my site in another browser (default one) instead of Google Chrome then this A2HS prompt appears again and the user gets the second installation of the App.

Can I somehow restrict the second installation of the App? Maybe I should specify some property in [manifest.json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)?

Comment: I am geeting error that windows is not define when i am adding below code.                                                           

window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", ev => { 
  // Stop Chrome from asking _now_
  ev.preventDefault();

  // Create your custom "add to home screen" button here if needed.
  // Keep in mind that this event may be called multiple times, 
  // so avoid creating multiple buttons!
  myCustomButton.onclick = () => ev.prompt();
});

Comment: Hi, I suppose that you don't have 'window**s**' object in your execution scope. Is it 'window**s**' or 'window' as in your snippet?